# How to use PM2 Process Manager with SvelteKit

Tags: environment-variables, pm2, sveltekit

I am trying to manage my **SvelteKit** build with **PM2** (Process Manager) — my problem is that I can't succesfully inject a `.env`-file using an `ecosystem.config.cjs`. My files currently look like this:

`.env.production`

```bash
PORT=3000
```

The only changing thing in both configs is at:
`env: { }`

`ecosystem.config.cjs` (working **fine** - app runs on provided port)

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'my_app',
            script: './build/index.js',
            watch: false,
            ignore_watch: ['database'],
            autorestart: true,
            // --------------------------------------------------
            // if passed directly PORT is being used as expected:
            // --------------------------------------------------
            env: {
                PORT: 3000
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

`ecosystem.config.cjs` (**not** working - injected `PORT` variable is being ignored)

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'my_app',
            script: './build/index.js',
            watch: false,
            ignore_watch: ['database'],
            autorestart: true,
            // ----------------------------------------------------
            // when I try to inject a .env it's just being ignored:
            // ----------------------------------------------------
            env: {
                ENV_PATH: "./.env.production",
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Any help is much appreciated and thanks for reading!
Cheers,
Boris

**EDIT:** Made question a bit more clear + added answer below

Comment: You say (not working) can you explain? Do you have error messages? error logs? etc.

Comment: @Alaindeseine No, no error logs since there was no error (just the env-var being ingnored). But I figured it out, so thanks for reminding me to close this. Answer incoming.

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the injection of `.env.production`, but the `PORT` environment variable. `PORT` must be provided directly and can't be part of `.env.production` (well, it can be but will be ignored).
There's probably another way, but the following works:

`ecosystem.config.cjs`

```js
module.exports = {
    apps: [
        {
            name: 'my_app',
            script: './build/index.js',
            watch: false,
            ignore_watch: ['database'],
            autorestart: true,
            // ----------------------------------------------------
            // when I try to inject a .env it's just being ignored:
            // ----------------------------------------------------
            env: {
                PORT: 3000,
                ENV_PATH: "./.env.production",
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

`.env.production`

```bash
# production
PUBLIC_test=value
```